# How to give permission to my current user

Tags: command-line, permissions

so basically i want to able to write data using stfp but when I use it. it says permission denied. I want to be able to do it in this directory `/home/user` so when I use `ls -l` command it has following output

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 21:43 FOLDER1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 22:00 FOLDER2
```

How can i see who is the owner of this dir. I know i can use this cmd `chmod a+rw user`
to give everyone read and write permission to everyone but i just wanna give it to only one user. And there is only one user in system but i might create more in future.
I wanna understand concept of owner and groups.
Additional questions:-
how to see what groups are there. how to create groups and how to add users to that groups.

Comment: TBH, I dont encourage you to do it. Every sftp can access his home directory which should be suffice, if they need access to a specific folder like /var/www/ you can provide, but letting one user accessing another users home directory by chaning permissions,  I wont recommend that

Answer (score 2):

Very good and correct answer by [yxz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKyO.png)

The only thing that would improve it is an actual example (even though it is implied).
As I may not comment yet (not enough reputation points) I have to write an additional answer in order to provide examples.

Simplified command syntax:

```
sudo chown username[:[groupname]] <filename>
sudo chown username[:[groupname]] <dirname>
```

For the following examples these are the parameters

- user name: **jack**
- login group name: **ptimer**
- group name: **accounts**
- file name: **foo**
- dir name: **clients**

The file `foo` exists on the system named `server` in the share named `data` in the directory `clients`. **i.e.** `//sever/data/clients/foo`

### Examples: change file ownership

```
1. admin@server:/data$ sudo chown jack clients/foo  
2. admin@server:/data$ sudo chown jack: clients/foo  
3. admin@server:/data$ sudo chown jack:accounts clients/foo
```

1. change owner of *file* named `foo` to **jack**
2. change owner of *file* named `foo` to **jack** and group **ptimer**. Jack is a member of the *login group* named **ptimer**. In this example the *login group* is implied by the use of **`:`** after the owner name
3. change owner of *file* named `foo` to **jack** and group to `accounts`

### Examples: change directory ownership

```
4. **admin@server:/data$** sudo chown jack clients  
5. admin@server:/data$ sudo chown jack: clients  
6. admin@server:/data$ sudo chown jack:accounts client  
7. admin@server:/data$ sudo chown -R jack:accounts client
```

4. change owner of *directory* named `clients` to **jack**
5. change owner of *directory* named `clients` to **jack** and group **ptimer**
6. change owner of *directory* named `clients` to **jack** and group to `accounts`
7. change owner of *directory* and all files in the directory named `clients` to **jack** and group to `accounts`

For more help see:

```
chown --help  
man chown
info chown
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ls -l` output, the 3rd and 4th column are the user (owner) and group (owner) respectively, so your folders are both owned by root.

If you run `chmod +006 yourfile`, this gives all users read and write permission to `yourfile`. In this case, `root` owns the folder, so you would need to use `sudo` (or some other method to issue the command as root). If you only want a single user or a few to have access, you can use `chown userowner[:groupowner]` (with `sudo`) to make that user or group the owner of the file and use `chmod +600` to give read write to owner and `chmod +060` to give read write to group owner.

To list the groups the current user belongs to, use `groups username`.
To list all groups you can use `cat /etc/group`. `getent group` also works.

To create a new group, use `groupadd`.

To add a user to a group, use `usermod -Ga groupname username`. If you do not use the `-a` flag, the user `username` is removed from all current groups and only present in the new group `groupname`.

Comment: The `ls -l` output OP provided has only three rows, so how it comes that there is some information in the forth row? Also the `command chmod +600 username` will end up with an error message unless a file named `username` exists in the current directory. Also you can't use chmod on a file owned by root without using sudo. Your answer is just wrong in to many points, sorry, but you shouln learn more about permissions and look at the man pages for the commands befor posting an answer.

Comment: sorry I meant the third and forth column. by `username`, I meant to insert OP's username or the username that they want to use. Using `sudo` is something I should have hinted but there are other ways (to become superuser (not that this is recommended)).

Comment: Please take a look at `man chmod`, you need to provide a filename, not a username.

Comment: @mook765 sorry you are right, I got `chmod` and `chown` mixed up

Comment: `groups` without specifying a user will not list the groups present on the system, but rather will print the groups for the current process.